# Adjust screen backlight on ancient HP, with Lubuntu 15.10

Tags: lubuntu, laptop, 15.10, brightness, backlight

I've installed Lubuntu 15.10 on my HP nx9005 (circa 2001), and all works great except that I can find no way to adjust the backlight brightness.

I've had a look at various solutions, here and elsewhere, including adding

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

to grub (nothing), `xbacklight` (cannot get it to run) and using `xrandr` to adjust brightness (alters / screen / brightness, but not /backlight/ brightness - the only thing which did anything) but to no avail.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to use the original keys (<kbd>Fn + F1</kbd>,  <kbd>Fn + F2</kbd>), but will settle for almost anything (within reason).  I still have an Ubuntu 10.04 installation on which this works fine.  I believe the graphics card is Radeon, processor is Athlon XP-M.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's applicable on your machine, but I have sometimes had luck using another approach than the GRUB_CMDLINE one. You might do better fixing settings in xorg's conf.d directories.
Here is a good guide on how one might do that:
http://itsfoss.com/fix-brightness-ubuntu-1310/

The guide is for Ubuntu 14.04, but I've had luck with it in Ubuntu 15.10 as well.